# C# windows explorer right click function

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I dont know what this is called sorry im not the best programmer. I have tried to search google but i dont even know how to ask google. I want to be able to call a function from my C# win form program on a file when user right clicks the file.

Example like winrar extracting files i want to be able to call my program function on files in windows explorer.

```
Solution:
  RegistryKey key;
  key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"*\shell");
  key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"*\shell\My Encryptor");
  key.SetValue("",Application.StartupPath);
  key.Close();
```

Comment: You want to [add context menu items like this](http://www.askvg.com/add-cascading-menus-for-your-favorite-programs-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/) programmatically, I think.

Comment: Ok the duplicate link given shows how its done but not programatically which is not hard. This is my solution now works with all files